# Google Chrome not starting

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, startup-applications

I am running 14.04 with latest update 3.13.0-30-generic. After restarting post update I found that Google Chrome is not launching.
I am able to launch Google-Chrome from command line but if I close the terminal window the chrome window closes too!
A new icon  appeared in launcher so I locked into launcher but after closing the terminal window (the one used to launch Chrome), the icon does not relaunch chrome.

I also found that the incorrect app name appear up in the menu "SecuStore" instead of "Google Chrome"

Comment: OK solved:</p>

1) Open you file browser ("Files" in the launcher)</p>
2) Then go up to "edit" in the top of screen menu bar and select preferences.</p>
3) Then tick "Show hidden and backup files"</p>
4) Go back to your file browser and  scroll down to ".local" and open the folder.</p>
5) Then open "share" folder.</p>
6) Open "applications" folder.</p>
7) Select every folder with chrome in it's name and trash (empty trash)</p>
8) Open the launcher "Search your computer and online sources" App in the launcher and search for Google Chrome and launch... </p>    ...problem solved!

Comment: Please don't add answers as comments. You can post answers to your own questions and delete your own comments, if you feel they're obsolete.

Comment: Ctrl-H is an easier way to make it show hidden files.

Comment: Drat.  I found the file but it still gives me the spinner then just quits.

Answer (score 19):

I was able to fix this by deleting all files in `/home/USERNAME/.config/google-chrome/` which forces Google Chrome to regenerate all configuration and profile files. You should be able to do this with a single command:

```
rm ~/.config/google-chrome/*
```

Keep in mind that **this will delete all of your bookmarks and settings**. So (hopefully!) you have them synced with your Google account or backup somehow.

You can change folder's owner.. it worked for me `sudo chown username ~/.config/google-chrome/`... Good luck.

Comment: Nope.  Same result.  Spinner but no start.

Comment: @SDsolar use `sudo rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/*` It will delete all files and folders under `google-chrome` folder

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue when I run `google-chrome` from terminal,

I found that it needed a new version of NSS: Chrome 62 need `NSS>=3.26`. So I installed `libnss3`.

```
$google-chrome

[6999:7036:1113/200616.549496:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)

sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss3
```

and it started working.

Comment: cool... this doesn't deletes my bookmark.. this should be the correct answer, since bookmarks are crucial (which I have tons)...

Comment: Awesome. This work for me. I had issue with chrome 63 and latest chromium browser with Ubuntu 14. It resolved for both the browsers.

Comment: Admire your effort!

Comment: Had the same issue, when I click Google Chrome it will appear and disappear quickly. Reinstalling libnss3 solved the problem for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I could not get Chrome to start if I downloaded the installer from Google's website. But, I found that if I used the terminal command `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable` it installed and worked.

Comment: Here it is 2017 and that is not found, nor any other variation I tried.

Comment: sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable is worked for me in  2017 .thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also may have to show hidden files and go to .config.  For me, the rights to the google-chrome directory in there got set to root so I had no rights for google-chrome to create directories as needed.  Change the owner to your login, folder access to Create and Delete files, group to your login, and access files as folder access for group and Other.

I used nemo (in LinuxMint) with elevated privileges to do this.  It can be done with the command prompt commands but I'm not to familiar with them yet.

After this change  google-chrome now runs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are in 2017.  Things have changed some.

I just had this happen and fixed it today.  And yes, it says Chromium.

After trying the usual remedies I found all over the web such as navigating into various local directories and clearing out files, etc., it still wouldn't work.

I couldn't even uninstall it and try a reinstall because I didn't know the package name.

So here is what worked:

Go into the Ubuntu Software Center (Press the Windows key and type "soft" and it will find it)

Search for Chromium - It found it when I typed just "chro"

I told it to uninstall it.  Took just a minute or two.

Once uninstalled, I rebooted.

Then I went back into the Ubuntu Software Center, searched for it again then told it to install it.

It did so.

And it worked.

**Then when I logged it back into Google (from the Settings menu) it restored my extensions and bookmarks and everything.  (The former Chromium wouldn't connect to Chrome settings but they have updated it so it works fine now)**

Now it is acting normal.