# Both Google Chrome & Chromium are not working

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, browser, google

I used Google Chrome all the time in by browsing time; I think then I tried to upgrade the system to 16.04 (but failed) and now google chrome is not working (not sure if that is the reason or not).

It shows me this error:

```
[6405:6437:0806/161203:ERROR:nss_util.cc(744)] Error initializing NSS with a persistent database (sql:/home/maldini/.pki/nssdb): /usr/lib/libsoftokn3.so: undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure
[6405:6437:0806/161203:ERROR:nss_util.cc(212)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -5925
[6405:6437:0806/161203:FATAL:nss_util.cc(214)] nss_error=-5925, os_error=0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've been searching a lot to solve this, and every time I see people refer to the answer here: [Google Chrome error: Error initializing NSS without a persistent database](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801838/google-chrome-error-error-initializing-nss-without-a-persistent-database)

I tried it, and it is not working. 
Other solutions I found is to install and use Chromium Browser. I did installed it but it didn't work neither and it shows me the same error above.

**Update**

This is the output from the terminal when I try to run chromium as sudo:

```
sudo chromium-browser 
[0820/003010:ERROR:nss_util.cc(98)] Failed to create /home/maldini/.pki/nssdb directory.
[0820/003010:FATAL:chrome_main_delegate.cc(411)] Check failed: process_type.empty(). Unable to get the user data directory for process type: zygote
#0 0x7f3b087afdee base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x7f3b087ce42e logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#2 0x5646620584eb <unknown>
#3 0x7f3b10187da2 <unknown>
#4 0x7f3b101867fd content::ContentMain()
#5 0x5646620578ea <unknown>
#6 0x7f3afce73830 __libc_start_main
#7 0x5646620577a9 <unknown>
```

The output of

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 244298 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (52.0.2743.116-1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (52.0.2743.116-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/google-chrome (google-chrome) in auto mode
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
```

Comment: Have you try to uninstall Google chrome and reinstalling it again? something must have gone wrong with the upgrade to break Google chrome, were you able to upgrade your system?

Comment: @RobGoss I did uninstalled and installed it many times; and it didn't work. Also, I couldn't upgrade my system but for now its ok, I only need Chrome back.

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit version of Chrome or 64-bit you can try Chromium it also works well. if your machine is a 32 bit you will not be able to install Google as Google dropped the 32 bit version

Comment: @RobGoss I'm using 64-bit. I installed Chromium too but it didn't work; it shows me the same error.

Comment: How did you remove Google chrome and what commands did you use you may have left some packages if not removed correctly

Comment: @RobGoss "sudo apt-get purge" and I also deleted all the caches and config files from google chrome that I had before.

Comment: update and upgrade your system with: `sudo apt-get update`. `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: @Maldini Please don't add "no sol yet!" to the title.

Comment: @edwinksl thought it would help to have some people to fix the problem.

Comment: @L.D.James of course I tried that and it did not fix the problem.

Comment: @Maldini - The latest version of `chromium` is not stable. Please revert to an older working version. Don't know about chrome.

Comment: @Raphael I tried to install older versions of Chromium and Chrome, but both did not work.

Comment: @Maldini - Which version did you try? For me only version `50.*` works.

Comment: @Raphael I don't quiet remember. I tried to install any 50.* version but could not find one in: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/google-chrome-stable

Comment: @Maldini - Here's the [version 50.*](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/9739028/+files/chromium-browser_50.0.2661.102-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1237_amd64.deb) of chromium.

Comment: @Raphael I couldn't install it. It needs both chromium-codecs-ffmpeg and chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra. I don't know why but I can't install them both it says:     chromium-codecs-ffmpeg : Conflicts: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra but 49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233 is to be installed
 chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra : Conflicts: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg but 49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233 is to be installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45181/discussion-between-raphael-and-maldini).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

```
$ google-chrome-stable 
[12296:12330:0719/235802.416830:ERROR:nss_util.cc(706)] Error initializing NSS with a persistent database (sql:/home/andy/.pki/nssdb): /usr/lib/libsoftokn3.so: undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure
[12296:12330:0719/235802.416884:ERROR:nss_util.cc(201)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -5925
[12296:12330:0719/235802.416891:FATAL:nss_util.cc(203)] nss_error=-5925, os_error=0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I found that libnss3-nssdb was removed and libnss3 was upgraded in a partial upgrade on my Ubuntu 16.04. Now I try to install libnss3-nssdb:

```
$ sudo apt install libnss3-nssdb 
...    
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss3-nssdb : Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.21-1ubuntu4) but 2:3.26.2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

then downgrade libnss3:

```
$ sudo apt install libnss3=2:3.21-1ubuntu4
```

Finally it works.

Comment: This right, work for me, iam downgrade not to `libnss3=2:3.21-1ubuntu4`  but `libnss3=2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7`. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

From your errors and the output of your comments you have been running applications as elevated user which is making you loose permission to parts of your home folder.

You can fix this by running this command to give permission back to you userID:

```
$ sudo chown -R [youruserID]:[youruserID] ~[youruserID]
```

Change `[youruserID]` to the username you login with.  Don't include the brackets in the command.  The second `[youruserID]` is your groupID which is by default the same as your userID.

I was able to duplicate the error in your question by running the same command you ran:

```
$ sudo chromium-browser
```

After you have fixed your personal with the `chown` command above, reinstall Google chrome by downloading the latest provided by Google from:
https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/

Install it either by Double Clicking the `deb` file from your file browser, or from the commandline with:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

For the `Chromium` install it directly from the default repository the same way you did the first time:

```
$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried doing this before and I just tried it again but it did not solve the problem unfortunately. Also, every time I start up my computer the "system program problem detected" pops up three times, I usually press "report the problem" but nothing happens yet. I also get the same message/dialog when I try to open Chromium or Google Chrome.

Comment: @Maldini Can you give the output of `$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`.  I can't make out the exact errors in the your question.  Please append it to your question.

Comment: I added the output in the question. It doesn't show any error when I try to install Google Chrome nor Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for you. I was getting a related error message and solved it by calling `chromium-browser --user-data-dir=/path/to/some/temp/directory/i/made/up/to/hold/my/browsing/profile/and/history`.

HTH.