# Google Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop Can't Running, Error initializing NSS with a persistent database

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, google-chrome

Previously, I performed `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` OS from terminal, after which google-chrome-stable could not run.

I've reinstalled google-chrome-stable on My local, but it's still an error when running google-chrome-stable.

Here, error when running **google-chrome-stable**

```
$ sudo google-chrome-stable 
[4698:4698:0731/160305:ERROR:nss_util.cc(712)] Error initializing NSS with a persistent database (sql:/home/sts/.pki/nssdb): libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[4698:4698:0731/160305:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -5925
[4698:4698:0731/160305:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-5925, os_error=0
```

I am already read from link, but not solve for me -_-

[Google Chrome error: Error initializing NSS without a persistent database](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808709/google-chrome-error-initializing-nss-without-a-persistent-database)

[Google Chrome: Error initializing NSS without a persistent database](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801838/google-chrome-error-error-initializing-nss-without-a-persistent-database/938561#938561)

Can Help me for this problem? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can look at this similar error: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91962 Comment #31 seem to has a workaround.

Comment: My NSS error code is -5925

I am already run of the syntax `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/ /usr/lib/nss` but symlink already exists

Comment: Is your Ubuntu 32 or 64-bit? Chrome no longer distributes versions for 32-bit. And why are you running it with `sudo`?

Comment: @MichaelBay My ubuntu version is 64bit, I run with the command `sudo` because if it only runs with `google-chrome-stable` there is an error `Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: You shouldn't run any graphical software with sudo. That's where your problem started, most likely, with some other software messing with permissions.

Comment: Nah, in here all permissions of source `google-chrome-stable` already i changes to my user local's, Sir. But this doesn't work, I can't running chrome on my local -__-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that libnss3-nssdb was removed and libnss3 was upgraded in a partial upgrade on my Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

libnss3-nssdb depends on libnss3

Now I try to install libnss3-nssdb :

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnss3-nssdb
...............................................
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libnss3-nssdb : Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7) but 2:3.26.2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And I get the broken package when it will install `libnss3-nssdb`

> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Now, downgrade the version libnss3-nssdb to `2: 3.15.4-1ubuntu7`.

```
sudo apt install libnss3=2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7
```

After downgrade, I can running chrome apps on my local.

This it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is something from IKW Administrators that I found at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=483774

Create these two symbolic links:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nss/libsoftokn3.so /usr/lib/libsoftokn3.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nss/libnssdbm3.so /usr/lib/libnssdbm3.so
```

Now at least I can start and run Chromium. But I'm still out of the woods. Now Chromium distrusts 100% of SSL certificates, giving error message

> ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(974)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for update.googleapis.com failed err=-8179

Comment: Ah, the certificate problem resolved by adding the link `ln -s /usr/lib/nss/libnssckbi.so /usr/lib/libnssckbi.so` h/t Don Ziemba https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/44167