# Error initializing NSS when trying to launch Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

```
[5945:5982:1218/174102.621327:ERROR:nss_util.cc(650)] Error initializing NSS with a persistent database (sql:/home/amal/.pki/nssdb): libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[5945:5982:1218/174102.621403:ERROR:nss_util.cc(154)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -5925
[5945:5982:1218/174102.621416:FATAL:nss_util.cc(156)] nss_error=-5925, os_error=0
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to explain where you get these messages and what is actually happening when you get them?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when upgrading Kubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04.  I found the following AskUbuntu post helpful; [Google Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop Can't Running, Error initializing NSS with a persistent database](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941455/google-chrome-on-ubuntu-14-04-desktop-cant-running-error-initializing-nss-with)

In short, run the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-nssdb
sudo apt install libnss3=2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7
```

In addition, I had to run the following command after getting errors that I was running an older version of Chromium than my profile was created for (most likely referring the the version of libnss3).  You may have to restore bookmarks and other settings after running this command.

```
mv ~/.config/chromium/ chromium_bkup-nss-issue
```