# Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox hang when trying to upload or download a file. I suspect an NSS problem

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, openssl

In both Mozilla firefox and Google Chrome, when I attempt to upload or download a file (including a photo), the browser hangs.  I can clear the hang with kill -2 PID but I'd rather not do that.
When I start chrome, I get the following error message:
 `[1320750:1320844:1205/224205.121619:ERROR:nss_util.cc(349)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018`
It isn't clear to me that this is the problem, but there are no other error messages or indications of a problem that I can find, so this is where my investigation went..

I did a little googling (ironic, ain't it)(hint to the wise: when searching, exclude the - in -8018.  The - means "exclude this word" which is the opposite of what we want to do).  I found [Error at startup (nss_util.cc(349)) with the AppImage version 1.1.1](https://github.com/upscayl/upscayl/issues/26) which referred me to [Error initializing NSS when trying to launch Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987406/error-initializing-nss-when-trying-to-launch-google-chrome).  It suggested installing libnss3-nssdb, which I tried to do and failed: apt can't locate package libnss3-nssdb.  However, I did reinstall all of the libnss3 packages and apt picked up libnspr4-dev automatically.  That cleared the error message from nss_util.cc but did not solve the problem about hanging on upload or download.

Now, in thinking about this problem a little more, there is something that I notice that I do *not* see.  When I attempt to upload or download a file, a file selector dialog box should open and allow me to select the name of the file to upload from or download to.  I don't see that.  Could that be the issue?  How would I go about troubleshooting that?

I am running the 5.15.0-52-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP kernel.  I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.  Mate 1.26.0, lightdm 1.30.0.
I am running Firefox 107.0.1 and Chrome 108.0.5359.94.

Thank you